# How to get the SubjectKeyId from a tls.Certificate?

Tags: go, ssl

I'm using go with MDNS and need to announce the SubjectKeyId with the MDNS record. The SKI is part of the x509 certificate, but not readable from the final TLS certificate:

```
priv, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

template := x509.Certificate{
    SerialNumber: big.NewInt(1),
    Subject: pkix.Name{
        Organization: []string{"Acme Co"},
    },
    NotBefore:             time.Now(),
    NotAfter:              time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24 * 180),
    KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageKeyEncipherment | x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature,
    ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
    BasicConstraintsValid: true,
}

derBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, publicKey(priv), priv)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create certificate: %s", err)
}

tlsCert := tls.Certificate{
    Certificate: [][]byte{derBytes},
    PrivateKey:  priv,
}
```

How can I extract or generate the SKI from the resulting `tls.Certificate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build it yourself and provide it as the `SubjectKeyId` of your certificate template.

[RFC 5280 section 4.2.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2) suggests a couple of potential methods for generating the subject key identifier. The most popular is to just take the SHA1 hash of the ASN.1 encoding of the public key. For example, if `pub` is an `*rsa.PublicKey`, you could do:

```
keyBytes := x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(pub)
keyHash := sha1.Sum(keyBytes)
ski := keyHash[:]
```

and then just set the `SubjectKeyId` field of your certificate template to `ski` before calling `x509.CreateCertificate`.